# Как узнать почему не срабатывает скрипт в ie?

Tags: javascript

Вот кусок скрипта. Почему-то в ie не создается блок в коде. При этом ошибок в консоли нет, просто не появляется секция. В чем может быть проблема (версия ie 11)

```
item.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let div = document.createElement('div'),
    title = this.querySelector('h3').textContent;
    div.className = 'popup-doctor';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    document.body.querySelector('.popup-doctor').innerHTML = '<div class="popup-doctor"><div class="wrap-popup-doctor"><div class="wrap-popup-doctor-close">Закрыть</div><div class="cart-content"></div></div></div>';
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      method: 'POST',
      data: 'name=' + title,
      success: function(data){
        let popUpCart = document.querySelector('.cart-content');
            popUpCart.innerHTML = data;
      }
    });
```

Comment: вы можете над этим не думать, если подключите babel к своему проекту, и настроите его для ie11

Comment: какая именно часть не работает? добавление элемента `.popup-doctor`? или добавление данных после ajax?

Comment: let div = document.createElement('div') не работает, по крайней мере в коде блок не появляется

Comment: @narem, добавь лог после этой строчки - и выведи div